# Can something act both as an object and a function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a programmatic interface to my api, I have the following routes

```
'api/location/:locationId/users' get, post
'api/location/:locationId/users/:userId' get, post, put
```

I would like to to use it like this

```
var myApi = new API('baseUrl');
myApi.api.location(locationId).users.get()
myApi.api.location(locationId).users.post(data)
myApi.api.location(locationId).users(userID).get()
myApi.api.location(locationId).users(userID).post(data)
myApi.api.location(locationId).users(userID).put(data)
```

so I started writing the class and realized it's not straight forward

```
class API{
  constructor(baseUrl) {
    this.axios = axios.create({ baseURL });;
  }
  this.api = {
     location: (locationId) => {
        users: ...(stuck)
     }
  }
}
```

I know there's different ways of doing it, but I am wondering if it's "possible" to have something act both as a function and object in javascript

ie.

```
var a = ..?..
a(blah) // returns an output
a.get(blah) // returns an output
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible...but you need a *function*. `function fn() {}; fn.myMethod = () => {}`. It's not impossible to do with `new` but super hackly, as you have to override what the `new` keyword does. You are better off using a constructor function without `new` that will return a function with properties/methods or use a factory method for one. You might also do it via proxies but I think it's also hacky

Comment: Any [JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) **is** an object. And you can definitely customize it to do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly is possible:

```js
var myObj = {
  someFunc: () => "foo"
}

myObj.someFunc.bar = "baz";

console.log(myObj.someFunc());
console.log(myObj.someFunc.bar);
```

Functions are objects just like almost everything else in JavaScript. That means you can add properties to them.

Comment: Anyway to do it in a single declartaion?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. thanks @Cerbrus

```
class API {
  constructor(baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.api = {
       location: (locationId) => ({
          users: (() => {
            var a = (userId) => ({
              get: () => `${this.baseUrl}/api/location/${locationId}/users/${userId}`
            })
            a.get = () => `${this.baseUrl}/api/location/${locationId}/users`;
            return a
          })()
       })
    }
  }
}
var myApi = new API('baseUrl');
myApi.api.location('locationId').users.get()
// "baseUrl/api/location/locationId/users"
myApi.api.location('locationId').users('userId').get()
// "baseUrl/api/location/locationId/users/userId"
```